# react - Cannot read property '_currentElement' of null

Tags: reactjs

Rollbar is catching a ton of react errors while unmounting components.

below stack trace is from a single unmount, which then goes deeeep into unmounting children and eventually throws an error.

Am I supposed to wrap `React.unmountComponentAtNode(elm)` in a try/catch? **Seems horrible.**

[image: react has trouble unmounting children]

Comment: I guess even a try/catch would not change your problem, which is, if I understand well, that your component is not unmounting properly ... More code may help here maybe ..

Comment: are there multiple ways to unmount something? is it a possible race condition where i'm unmounting an element at a node and then mounting one at the same node?

Comment: seems possible. But really hard to tell without knowing how mount and unmount things.